# C# Dynamic Query Without A Database Model

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic

I have been searching the web for a solution to dynamic queries.

I have found many different solutions (e.g. Linq to Sql, Dynamic Linq Expressions, Dynamic Query), but all of these solutions involve some sort of previous knowledge of the database (like a model in code).  Maybe what I am asking is way off the deep end, but is there any possible way to dynamically query a database without a model?

For example, a database has a `Customers` table with the following columns:

- CustomerID
- Name
- FavoriteColor

I want to create a query as `SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE @0 = @1`, where the two placeholders are populated dynamically.  The resulting data does not tie to a model class and I would prefer to use some sort of framework to build the queries, not simple string concatenation.

The System.Linq.Dynamic namespace came really close to fulfilling this request, but it uses a database model.

I realize this is crazy, but I was just curious.

Comment: It's not that crazy.  What flavor is your database? There are several approaches depending on what back end needs to be supported.

Answer (score 2):

Insight is similar to Dapper: https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database

Answer (score 0):

> SQL query parameters can only take the place of a literal value. You
>   cannot use a parameter for a table name, column name, list of values,
>   or other SQL syntax. That's standard SQL behavior across all brands of
>   database.

you cannot make your column names dynamic as far as I am aware of, the only way one can think of making this query dynamic is to use something like `string.Format` or `StringBuilder` in combination with some regex/rules that checks whether the columnName is a valid name if its a direct input from the user.. if its controlled by you then it shouldnt be a cos of worry since you can be rest assured that there wont be SQL injection. if the user is responsible for providing the column names make sure you map the user input to some column name in code.

Now the parameters themselves can be parametrized and for that you can stick to plain old ADO.NET with SqlCommand class and then add parameters to query dynamically. Here is a resource you can refer for the same: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06

Hope this helped..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Dapper: http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/